# How to implement listview with image like dealfish(OLX) application?

Tags: android, android-listview

I spent a lot of time to solve my problem. But not solution work.

1.I'm implement listview in my app. in listview item contain picture(from url) and text.

2.I'm load item to listview every 10 item and notifydatasetchange().

3.When notifydatasetchange() all picture was refresh Why?.

4.I want listview working like dealfish(OLX) application.

this code is after query 10 item and add item to list

```
if (CAdapter != null) {
    CAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and this code is in adapter getview method

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = Layf.inflate(R.layout.content_list_extend_item, null);

        holder.img_ContentImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_ContentImage);
        holder.tv_Title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_Title);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    final ContentExtendInfo contentInfo = ContentList.get(position);

    if(contentInfo != null){
        if(holder.img_ContentImage != null) {
            if (contentInfo.getPicture().length() > 0)
                new DownloadImageViewTask(context, holder.img_ContentImage).execute(contentInfo.getPicture());
            else
                holder.img_ContentImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_img);
        }

        if(holder.tv_Title != null)
            holder.tv_Title.setText(contentInfo.getTitle());
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

and this code is DownloadImageViewTask class

```
public class DownloadImageViewTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private ImageView bmImage;
    private Context context;

    public DownloadImageViewTask(Context context, ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public DownloadImageViewTask() {
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap img = null;

        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return img;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```